# numeric calendar vector for dynamic objects

Tags: r, date, vector

I've got some dynamic objects like this:

```
today <- as.Date(Sys.time())
this_month <- as.numeric(format(today,"%m"))
next_month <- this_month+1
month_after <- next_month+1
```

As you can probably guess, this is causing an issue given the fact there's no 13th month, therefore I need to provide a vector of values for the "next_motn" and "month_after" objects to choose from.
I'm thinking of something like this:

```
months <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12)
```

But I'm unsure of the syntax of how to make the code function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `lubridate::months` to add months to your original date, and then get the month:

```r
library(lubridate)
as.numeric(format(today + months(2), "%m"))
#[1] 1
```